# Load third parties libraries in his extensions with composer already used in others extensions

Tags: joomla-4.x, joomla-5.x

In my extension i load via composer the library ScssPhp\ScssPhp but in some sites there are others extensions installed which loads the same library ScssPhp\ScssPhp.

It's the ScssPhp\ScssPhp from my extension vendor which is always loaded by others.

What i should do ? Set a Prefix at the begining on all namespace declarations of ScssPhp\ScssPhp of my vendor directory ?

Comment: Can your extension check for the existence of the ScssPhp and only load it via composer if it is not already available?